# Why is IsDaylightSavingTime returning different value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dst

I have a piece of code that checks a time and then adds hours based on the daylight savings time value.

```
Dim CommentDateTime as Date = "11/2/2010 8:21:42 PM"
If CommentDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime Then
   'do something
Else
   'do something else
End If
```

The problem that I'm having is that IsDaylightSavingTime behaves differently on the production server than it does on the development.

On the development server the case is TRUE, but on the production it is false.

Both servers are running the same OS and are both running .NET 3.5

What information can I give to the SA to help troubleshoot my issue?

**UPDATE:**

The production server is in Arizona, a state that does not observe DST. I'm only concerned with knowing if a certain date/time is DST in the rest of the US that does observe it.

Here's how I fixed the problem:

```
If TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific StandardTime").IsDaylightSavingTime(CommentDateTime) Then
     'Do something
Else
     'Do something else
End If
```

My application only deals with locations located in the US, so this should do the trick.

Comment: This sounds like it's not a coding issue, but that your TimeZone settings are just different on the different machines. You might want to ask about this on ServerFault (and just summarize what the code does there rather than posting it there).

Comment: Read follwoing articles on how to convert to the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769%28VS.90%29.aspx and on how to deal with the Daylight Saving Time Issue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx#datetime_topic6

Comment: @Tim - Thanks for the advice. That's actually what I'm already doing, and I had it working fine on all the servers I tested until I moved the code to a production server in AZ.  AZ doesn't observe DST so no matter what date I put in, IsDaylightSavingTime will always return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daylight savings is calculated based on the regional settings of the server. Your dev box probably has different regional settings to your production box.

Comment: @OJ I didn't consider that IsDaylightSavingTime would only look at the timezone on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work:

`Dim CommentDateTime as Date = "11/2/2010 8:21:42 PM"
 TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(CommentDateTime)`

Good Luck!

Comment: @Zeroef, try this first. if it works, you can mark this as answer so other users will be helpful too. Thanks

Comment: I wish I could have marked both your answer and @OJ answer too.  The reason why I ultimately chose the other answer was because it was the root cause of the issue.  When I had "CommentDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime" in my code, it was just a shortcut of your answer in long form. But seeing the "CurrentTimeZone" made me realize, combined with @OJ's answer, that the server was using the local timezone to do the IsDST check.